# How do you create a new array from all NON empty values in another array?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4

```
   for ( int i = limit; i >= 0; i-- )
   {     
         if (  Low[i-1] >  Low[i]
            && Low[i+1] >  Low[i]
               ) Dpivot[i]=Low[i];
   }
```

This stores the **`Low`** price at such bar, where this condition is met into the **`Dpivot[]`** array.

But obviously, on bars that it isn't true, the value is 0.

How can I go about creating an array that has all the 0's skipped out and consists of only the actual prices that show up in `Dpivot[]`.

Sorry if this is a really trivial problem. I am very new to programming and `MQL4` documentation just leaves me with head pains.

I am really trying to wrap my head around this whole array thing!

My main problem in a lot of instances is to find values when conditions are met, but not being able to reference them again when they are not met, if this makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

### Corpus details will depend a lot on whether you build a Custom Indicator or some other type of the `MQL4` code-execution unit

The principal approach is to fill just non-zero cells into such a new array.

```
double aNewNonZeroPIVOTsARRAY[];

for ( int nPi = EMPTY,
          dPi = 0; dPi < ArraySize( Dpivot ); dPi++ ) {
      if  ( Dpivot[dPi] > 0. )  aNewNonZeroPIVOTsARRAY[++nPi] = Dpivot[dPi];
}
```

Comment: I am trying to build a custom indicator. So what you have said here will create an array which has only the non empty price values in order one after to other? I wana do this so i can do calculations to look at the difference between the most recent value and the last one before it (so for instance Dpivot [+1] is empty (0) but Dpivot [+2] has a price value instead of have the 0 value be +1 the +2 value which has a price in it is the +1 instead. Also be able to reference the values as co-ordinates for objects. So draw a line with the position of the Dpivot [+1] value to the Dpivot [0]?

Comment: Slow down, slow down, man. You ask more and more questions at once. **Yes,** this `for(){...}` **fills** `aNewNonZeroPIVOTsARRAY[]` array **only with non-zero values**, one after another, exactly as you have asked above.

Comment: Sorry!! My bad. All of those questions i asked are made possible if thats the case anyway lol! Thank you

Comment: Would you mind breaking down to me the mechanics of how the dpi and ++npi are being used? I see this is were the magic is happening but dont understand whats happening under the hood within the arrays and i feel i may get lost trying to apply this great solution in the future

Comment: The mechanics is well described in the MQL4 documentation. Read it and feel free to experiment with the code snippet inside your localhost copy to prove the concept. Inline pre-increment + inline post-increment is a common software syntax, you have used it before on your own ( ref. above ).

Comment: Okay ive had a look. Not at pc to experiment but may you clarify for me if this is whats happening. Npi is EMPTY which value is -1, if the array size is not less than dpi increment by 1 each time, which is going 1,2,3 etc inside the Dpivot [dpi] and checking for each of these to be greater than zero. If it is. The nonzeroarray[++npi]  is incrementing the -1 up to 0 for the current index value and assigning the value of the Dpivot from whatever position/index value [dpi] is now representing?

Comment: As said above, this is a **primitive forward-stepping scanner of your own array `Dpivot[]`** created above. For each non-zero value in `Dpivot[]` an appropriate copy is put inside ( densely stepped-forward ) `aNewNonZeroPIVOTsARRAY[]`, which was your own requirement. No zero elements get into `aNewNonZeroPIVOTsARRAY[]` as it is densely-stepped forward right via `++nPi` mechanics.

Comment: i tested this code. for some reason when i go to print the array, say the 0 index value. it just shoots zeroes at me lol